# How do you get a if statement between an Element and Infinity?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to have an if statment saying that if an element is equal to Infinity, it gives out a different phrase than "Infinity"(my element is an input box) here is my `if` statement:

```js
if (document.getElementById("box").value === Infinity) {
  document.getElementById("box").value = "STOP PRESSING BUTTONS"
}
```

I'm still very new to javascript/html so I might've gotten some of the terms wrong.

Comment: How does the code you provided not work? Could you maybe include a [mcve] in your question showing what you tried to do and how it doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: Luca-So my "box" element is the top part of a calculator where you can visualize all the numbers, etc. But when I go over my limit, it still displays "infinity". I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
if (result == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || result == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
{
    // ANY LOGIC
}
```

You could possibly use the [isFinite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) function instead, depending on how you want to treat [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NaN) `isFinite` returns `false` if your number is [POSITIVE_INFINITY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/POSITIVE_INFINITY), [NEGATIVE_INFINITY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY) or [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NaN).

```
if (isFinite(result))
{
    // ANY LOGIC
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's a text input, as I don't know of a way to enter Infinity in a number input.

Comment: And that would be `! isFinite(result)` :-)

Comment: never tried it but best guess is an element value will never equal Infinity